# Using "*" in string formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a function that downloads files which have this name structure:

```
cat.23123.mew.43424.jpg
dog.34454.ham.23433.jpg
cow.74754.moo.03434.jpg
```

For example, I just want to download the file whose name contains "cat" and "mew" and whatever else. As you see, the other part is made up by numbers that vary from file to file.

I tried this:

```
cat.*.mew.*.jpg
```

but it didn't download the requested file.
Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Can you show us your code? What is this function that downloads the files? What module is it using to request the URL that you are constructing?

Comment: @drewk Whoops didn't see that until after I posted my answer :/

Comment: Indeed, I had a similar reaction after reading it again.

Comment: @ArditSulce To what is `'cat.*.mew.*.jpg'` being input?

Comment: This isn't really a string-formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), for example:

```
if re.match(r'^cat\..*\.mew\..*\.jpg$', 'cat.23123.mew.43424.jpg'):
    # ...
```

If you know there must always be 5 digits, you could use something like this:

```
^cat\.\d{5}\.mew\.\d{5}\.jpg$
```

Comment: The files I want to download are listed on a HTTP site (http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD11A1.005/2012.07.11/), and this solution would not work with HTTP requests.

Comment: I think you'd have to parse that page with something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), extract the file URLs, and then check for matches using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use wildcards in HTTP GET requests.

Take a look at the smaller second file you downloaded, it's most likely an error page.